# Preserving DOM after ajax call

Tags: ajax, angular

I am new to Angular, and with many days of frustration, I have found that after Ajax call the DOM is remodelled, that cleared things for me but as I am pretty new to Angular, I cannot figure out how to keep it together. Right now when my Ajax call happens, the code breaks everything, I tried the following code after my Ajax request but now my carousel has disappeared.

```
this.currentIndex = 0;
this.slickConfig = {
  event: {
    afterChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      this.currentIndex = currentSlide; // save current index each time
    }
    init: function (event, slick) {
      slick.slickGoTo($scope.currentIndex); // slide to correct index when init
    }
  }
};
```

While init gives a red underline.
My ajax call is like following

```
this.httpClientService.postAjaxForm(link, postData)
  .subscribe(response => {
    if (response["x"] != undefined && response["x"] != null) {
       this.x= response["x"];  
       this.currentIndex = 0;
       this.slickConfig = {
          event: {
            afterChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
              this.currentIndex = currentSlide; // save current index each time
            }
            init: function (event, slick) {
              slick.slickGoTo($scope.currentIndex); // slide to correct index when init
            }
          }
        }; 
    }
```

Why the above call won't let my [carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) work normally and when ajax call is made why the page is broken?

Comment: Is it possible to do a plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @DeborahK I can but It won't work. Too many elements together, Basically my [slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) looses divs injected by the slider js after I receive an ajax call.